# Is is possible to use a query to specify a data type MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

For example, I want a column in table `A` to be of type `char(n)` where `n` = the number of entries in table `B`.

I'm aware that the motivations for doing this can be mitigated via relational database normalization, but sometimes you want to maintain simplicity/readability for simple projects.

In my case, `B` is a const reference table. I'm essentially using it to replicate the function of an `enum` without using the `set` type. I simply want to avoid having to change the int literal in `char(n)` every time I add a new entry to `B` ("add" as in "append another value to the `insert` statement which IMMEDIATELY follows the table definition in the SAME FILE, the ONLY place where values are inserted into `B`).

Comment: Why not just use `VARCHAR(n)` where `n` is the maximum possible number of entries in any of the tables?

Comment: Doesn't the number of rows in table B change over time? The datatype of a column can't change dynamically, you would have to use `ALTER TABLE` every time you need to change `n`

Comment: It sounds more like you're trying to replicate `SET`, not `ENUM`.

Comment: yes, I considered using the set datatype, but, in my schema, multiple columns in A have the same "varchar(n)" type, but sets can only be defined literally. Additionally, sets can only contain string values, which isn't great when you're storing bits rather than chars like I ended up doing.

Comment: I didn't mean you should use `SET`, just correcting what you're replicating.

Comment: Ahh... I see.  

Comment: This really sounds like a poor design. It has much the same problem as putting lists in a column. You should normalize the design.

Comment: You're probably right, and I may or may not take your advice, but would just like to add (in my defense, lol) that doing it my way allows me to replace some mildly convoluted and moderately verbose SQL statements in the backend with some very clean and elegant bitwise operations (I need to count the number of checked checkboxes that a user has in common with another user (for each other user).